# Attribute error: exp in python, works for some functions and not others

Tags: python, numpy, attributeerror, exp

I am writing code to graph a few different functions, many with exponentials. This is what I have:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> f13=Fraction('1/3')
>>> f23=Fraction('2/3')
>>> f43=Fraction('4/3')
>>> f53=Fraction('5/3')
>>> f12=Fraction('1/2')
>>> f32=Fraction('3/2')
>>> f56=Fraction('5/6')
>>> fm1=Fraction('-1')
>>> fm23=Fraction('-2/3')
>>> fm32=Fraction('-3/2')
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x=np.arange(0.01,2,0.01)
>>> xa=x/(1+0.1071*x)
>>> rate=(4.817e+6)*(x**fm23)*np.exp(-14.964/(x**f13))*(1+0.0325*(x**f13)-(1.04e-3)*   (x**f23)-(2.37e-4)*x-(8.11e-5)*(x**f43)-(4.69e-5)*(x**f53))+(5.938e+6)*(xa**f56)*(x**fm32)*np.exp(-12.859/(xa**f13))
```

And when I enter it, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
  rate=rate=(4.817e+6)*(x**fm23)*np.exp(-14.964/(x**f13))*(1+0.0325*(x**f13)-(1.04e-3)*   (x**f23)-(2.37e-4)*x-(8.11e-5)*(x**f43)-(4.69e-5)*(x**f53))+(5.938e+6)*(xa**f56)*(x**fm32)*np.exp(-12.859/(xa**f13))
AttributeError: exp
```

However, I have written the same code for this function:

```
>>> rate=(7.29e+2)+2.40*((10**3)*(x**fm32)*np.exp(-0.223/x))
```

And it works just fine. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy types don't mix well with `fractions.Fraction`.  In the expression `x**f13`, `x` is a normal NumPy array of dtype `float64`, but `f13` is `Fraction` object.  As a result of that, the expression `x**f13` is an array with dtype `object`, all of whose elements are (regular) Python floats, rather than NumPy floats.  This essentially means that NumPy couldn't figure out what type the results should be, so it ends up storing a collection of Python objects rather than a packed efficient homogeneously-typed array.

In the second expression you give, `-0.223/x` is a NumPy array of dtype `float64`, so there are no issues applying `np.exp` to it.

When you apply `np.exp` an array of dtype `object`, it goes through looking for an `exp` method on each element individually, and that gives you the `AttributeError` you're seeing.  Here's an example:

```
Python 2.6.9 (unknown, Nov 18 2013, 14:53:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([0.1, 0.2], dtype=object)
>>> np.exp(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: exp
```

Python 2.7.8 gives a slightly better error message that at least mentions the type of the object it failed to find the `exp` attribute on:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

It seems this error message was improved at some point between Python 2.7.5 and Python 2.7.8, though I'm not sure when.

Suggested solution: convert your `Fraction` instances to `float` before combining them with the NumPy arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> np.exp(np.arange(10) ** Fraction(1, 3))  # Fails as above
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: exp
>>> np.exp(np.arange(10) ** float(Fraction(1, 3)))  # Works.
array([ 1.        ,  2.71828183,  3.52514317,  4.23020126,  4.89102089,
        5.52882849,  6.15411272,  6.77291238,  7.3890561 ,  8.0051399 ])
```

Alternatively, avoid the `Fraction` type altogether.  It doesn't really buy you anything here - the exactness is lost as soon as you combine with floats anyway.

```
>>> f13 = 1.0 / 3.0  # Look Ma, no fractions!
>>> np.exp(np.arange(10) ** f13)
array([ 1.        ,  2.71828183,  3.52514317,  4.23020126,  4.89102089,
        5.52882849,  6.15411272,  6.77291238,  7.3890561 ,  8.0051399 ])
```

Comment: Hi, I am actually using python 2.7.5. I have tried to do it without importing numpy (so it's just exp(etc., etc.) and with from pylab import * instead of the matplotlib command and it gives me the same error message. I am slightly confused by your answer-are you saying to write, for instance, np.exp(-14.964/(x**float(f13)))?

Comment: I'd suggest not using the `Fraction` type at all: for example, just define `f13` as `1.0 / 3.0`.  That should avoid all of the above difficulties.

Comment: Ah, sorry;  it looks like the error message was improved at some point between 2.7.5 and 2.7.8 (which is what I was testing on).

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it works now. It's a shame to lose the accuracy that comes with floats-but I guess there's no way around it?

Comment: No, there's no easy way around it (beyond using some multiprecision arithmetic or symbolic algebra package, but then be prepared for things to get *much* slower).  At the point where you're applying the power operation to a `float` and a `Fraction`, converting the `Fraction` object to a `float` is about the only simple thing you can do to get an answer.  It would be surprising if the double-precision floats that Python uses didn't give enough precision for the application, though.